# Fetching values from url and displaying them

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

Hi I have following url from which I am trying to extract values.

```
http://xxxxxx.com/Confirm.aspx?vCode=123xyzd33eed&emailAddress=xxx@hotmail.com&
```

I am trying to extract the values of vCode and emailAddress to display in the appropriate fields.

```
 <input type="text" id="Text1" name="validationCode" value="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["validationCode"]); ?>" placeholder="validationCode"/>
        <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value="<? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["emailAddress"]); ?>" placeholder="Email Address" />
```

The above code doesnt display the values of vCode and emailAddress.
Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to fetch the data from the URL? jQuery AJAX?

Comment: Either jquery AJAX or aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/VgEWt/

```
function getParameterByName(uel, name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

url = "http://xxxxxx.com/Confirm.aspx?vCode=123xyzd33eed&emailAddress=xxx@hotmail.com&";

alert(JSON.stringify(getParameterByName(url, "vCode")));
alert(JSON.stringify(getParameterByName(url, "emailAddress")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["validationCode"]); ?>
```

or

```
<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET["validationCode"]) ?>
```

And don't use

```
<? echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["validationCode"]); ?>
```

Also, you use vCode in the query string, so make sure you're using the same names to get it.